# How do I batch update my app database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model

New to MVC and RoR and having a hard time grasping some of the concepts. One of them is batch updates to the database.

Lets say I have a set of data such as a list of students and their attributes like this

```
Student ID:1
Name: Alice
email:alice@alice.com
attribute: anything
attribute2: anything2
```

```
Student ID:2
Name: Kate
email:kate@kate.com
attribute: anything
attribute2: anything2
```

etc..

I've gotten the list from an API call.

I don't want them to be editable, nor do I want the attributes to be visible to the user.

Question is, how do I go about saving them into my database? It seems in the MVC way, each action requires a view? Will I be able to do it as a background process?

Thanks
Ryan

p/s- pointers to the right resources welcome too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'd just like to obtain records from an API and create models from them?

One option you may consider is writing rake tasks to get the data, and create the corresponding models (No rails answer is complete without a railscast link, so [here's one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) It's old, but tells the basics)

Going this route, you could avoid making the data publicly editable, and just get it into the models/DB

Comment: Hey Mike, partially correct. A user, say a teacher will need to be able to access his students list via an API, and the result will be al his students, WHICH would be updated into the appropriate database. In that essence it's not a one off data mine.

Comment: Ok, in this case, lets say you have a link: "Update Students", clicking this link will go through an established route, to a controller method where you will make the API call, parse the results and update attributes on the particular models. It will then have a redirect to the "students" view page. (Ideally this would be moved to a background worker queue, but will work fine for now)  Remember it's ok to sidestep the RESTful CRUD concepts in Rails, when you have a good reason.

Comment: Yup Mike that is the route I think is best! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You could use fixtures for this type of thing. Or, just use SQL to insert into your DB outside of Rails.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Fixtures.html